# Jenkins Pipeline Groovy pass in array to function

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting an array like this

```
def tags = [
    "zookeeper",
    "postgres",
    "postgres-maps",
    "kudu-master",
    "redis-master",
    "consul",
    "dcos-bootstrap"]
```

I'm trying to pass it into a function like

```
 run_linux("${tags}")
```

My function looks like

```
def run_linux(tags) {
  def tasks = [:]

  for (i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++) {
    def tag = "${tags[i]}"
    tasks["${tag}"] = {
       stage ("${tag}"){
            sh ..
       }
    }
```

So what it looks like in jenkins is this

```
[Pipeline] [[] stage
[Pipeline] [[] { ([)
[Pipeline] [z] stage
[Pipeline] [z] { (z)
[Pipeline] [o] stage
[Pipeline] [o] { (o)
[Pipeline] [k] stage
[Pipeline] [k] { (k)
```

It seems to be treating what got passed in as a string not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed passing a string into the `run_linux` function - specifically, the string `"${tags}"`, where `tags` is being coerced into a string via string interpolation.

Instead, try calling it like this: `run_linux(tags)`.